# Categorical attributes to Sparse Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

First of all I´m new to Machine Learning.

I am trying to predict the price of second hand cars. This cars have makes and models, so I used a MultiLabelBinarizer to make a sparse matrix, to handle the categorical attributes, here's the code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
encoder = MultiLabelBinarizer()
make_cat_1hot = encoder.fit_transform(make_cat)
model_cat_1hot = encoder.fit_transform(model_cat)
type_cat_1hot = encoder.fit_transform(type_cat)

print(type(make_cat_1hot))
carInfoModHot = carsInfoMod.copy()
carInfoModHot["makeHot"] = make_cat_1hot.tolist()
carInfoModHot["modelHot"] = model_cat_1hot.tolist()
carInfoModHot["typeHot"] = type_cat_1hot.tolist()



doors   km      make        year    makeHot                       modelHot  
5.0     78779   Mercedes    2012    [0, 0, 0,  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  
5.0     25463   Bmw         2015    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

Then I used it to make a prediction and get the mean square error with a Linear Regression:

```
lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

carsInfoTrainHot = carInfoModHot.drop(["price"], axis=1) # drop labels for training set

df1 = carsInfoTrainHot.iloc[:30000, :]
carsLabels1 = carsInfoMod.iloc[:30000, 3]
print(carsInfoTrainHot.head())
df2 = carsInfoTrainHot.iloc[30001:60000, :]
carsLabels2 = carsInfoMod.iloc[30001:60000, 3]
df3 = carsInfoTrainHot.iloc[60001:, :]
carsLabels3 = carsInfoMod.iloc[60001:, 3]

lr.fit(df1, carsLabels1) 
print(carsInfoTrainHot.shape)
carPrediction = lr.predict(df2)

lin_mse = mean_squared_error(carsLabels2, carPrediction)

lin_rmse = np.sqrt(lin_mse)
```

But I get this error:

> ---
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        12 carsLabels3 = carsInfoMod.iloc[60001:, 3]
>        13 
>   ---> 14 lr.fit(df1, carsLabels1)
>        15 print(carsInfoTrainHot.shape)
>        16 carPrediction = lr.predict(df2)
>
> /home/vagrant/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py
>   in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
>       510         n_jobs_ = self.n_jobs
>       511         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'],
>   --> 512                          y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
>       513 
>       514         if sample_weight is not None and np.atleast_1d(sample_weight).ndim > 1:
>
> /home/vagrant/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
>   in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy,
>   force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output,
>   ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype,
>   estimator)
>       519     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
>       520                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
>   --> 521                     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
>       522     if multi_output:
>       523         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,
>
> /home/vagrant/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
>   in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy,
>   force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
>   ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
>       400         # make sure we actually converted to numeric:
>       401         if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind == "O":
>   --> 402             array = array.astype(np.float64)
>       403         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
>       404             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

From what I understand is that I´m inserting an array in the categorical attributes, but how else can I change the categorical values to a sparse matrix?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of error. Also can you add some samples of data on which this error occurs?

Comment: Post a sample or link to dataset if possible and also the full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added more info.

Comment: The makeHot, modelHot etc columns in your data are lists in single sample. So that makes it a list of list for the whole column. This is not how you do one-hot encoding. In one-hot encoding you need to make individual columns for each value and then fill them with 0 and 1 which are absent and present respectively. Show the actual data and we can help you simply using `pandas.get_dummies()`. With current code, it will be unnecessary work arounds to solve this.

Comment: The original value of makeHot, is what you can find under "make" and modelHot is the result of doing MultiLabelBinarizer on the colum model with is made of car models.